# Crashes due to no access to SDL functions outside of main function

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I've been trying to improve my C++ skills and explore different ways of programming in it by using libraries like SDL.

This particular program is a Particle system and i've followed a guide on youtube that can be found here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Z5FI5180oo&list=UU6A2B9G_y-fzAXEu2hHPlMg.

The problem is that this guide is using SDL 1.2 and i've been trying to translate the depricated functions used in here to SDL 2.0.

Basically it works fine apart from some functions where i try to retrieve the width/height/pixels/pitch from the Windowsurface. SDL 1.2 uses the function GetVideoSurface() whereas i do believe SDL2.0 should use GetWindowSurface().

I'm having problems with accessing this function outside of my main function and i'm not sure what the problem really is.

For example in my particle::show() function i have this code:

```
void particle::show()
{
        Uint8* pixels=(Uint8*)SDL_GetWindowSurface(window)->pixels;
        Uint8* pixel=pixels+(int)y*SDL_GetWindowSurface(window)->pitch+(int)x;
        *pixel=color;
}
```

Here i can't access these functions, i get no error message. Even if i try to use SDL_GetError(). The program crashes with a segmentation fault and no other errors (that i can see.)

This is my main function:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("My Particles",
                         SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                         SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                         640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    bool running = true;
    const int FPS = 30;
    Uint32 start;
    srand(time(0));
    particleEngine ps (100, SDL_GetWindowSurface(window)->w/2, SDL_GetWindowSurface(window)->h/2);
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);



    while(running)
    {
        start = SDL_GetTicks();
        SDL_Event event;

        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            switch(event.type)
            {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                running = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);

        ps.refresh();

        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);


    }

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

I've defined my SDL_Window *window outside of every function as a global variable.
I'm running SDL 2.0 and Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite Beta 2

Any ideas how i should solve this?

Comment: You should try posting a short complete example.  In the code you posted the only `SDL_Window*` I see is local to main, it is not a global variable.  Perhaps, since you're using `particle` member functions you should be passing the pointer to the instance of the class and caching it there.

Comment: Note that there is *no* replacement for SDL_GetVideoSurface() of SDL 1.2. In SDL 2.0, you have to pass around the `window` you create in main(). Also, your `particle::show()` calls `SDL_GetWindowSurface(window)` - where does that `window` come from ? Where is it created/initialized ?

Comment: As stated above i've declared it just under the includes as SDL_Window *window; This does however obviously not work. Probably because i reinitate it in the main i guess? Should i try passing it to the ps.refresh function? Like ps.refresh(window) and then passing it from there into the particle::show() function?

Comment: If you have a global variable defined as `SDL_Window *window;` you have to initialize it somewhere. Perhaps your `SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow(...)`  in main() should just be `window = SDL_CreateWindow(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SDL_Window *window` is a local variable in the `int main(int argc, char** argv)` function. It will not be visible outside of `main` unless you either make it a global variable (not nice) or make it a member of a class which you create an instance of.

Alternatively you could pass the pointer to the SDL_Window to the functions which you need it in.

I noticed you said you have declared it as a global variable and in that case that is why it compiles but doesn't work. The variable used in the `particle::show()` will be using the global variable which will points to nothing (globals are always zero-initialized by default). As you declare SDL_Window again in main() that is what gets assigned the created window.

Comment: Globals are always zero-initialized.